# Multiple addons with the same name error but it's the same file __init__.py

Tags: python, add-on, error

[image]

Hi
I tried to install an addon from a zip file and i have this error but this is the same file. I checked, there is only 1 bl_info. There are 2 other .py files in the script, import_3ds.py and export_3ds.py, and neither of them have bl_info.
If i delete the `__init__.py` file there is no error but the plugin isn't loaded at all.

The `__init__.py` :

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

# <pep8-80 compliant>

bl_info = {
    "name": "Autodesk 3DS format",
    "author": "Bob Holcomb, Campbell Barton, Andreas Atteneder",
    "version": (2, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Import",
    "description": "Import 3DS, meshes, uvs, materials, textures, "
                   "cameras & lamps",
    "warning": "Images must be in file folder",
    "doc_url": "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/"
               "Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_3DS",
    "category": "Import-Export",
}

if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    if "import_3ds" in locals():
        importlib.reload(import_3ds)
    if "export_3ds" in locals():
        importlib.reload(export_3ds)


import bpy
from bpy.props import (
        BoolProperty,
        EnumProperty,
        FloatProperty,
        StringProperty,
        )
from bpy_extras.io_utils import (
        ImportHelper,
        ExportHelper,
        orientation_helper,
        axis_conversion,
        )


@orientation_helper(axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
class Import3DS(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    """Import from 3DS file format (.3ds)"""
    bl_idname = "import_scene.autodesk_3ds"
    bl_label = 'Import 3DS'
    bl_options = {'UNDO'}

    filename_ext = ".3ds"
    filter_glob: StringProperty(default="*.3ds", options={'HIDDEN'})

    constrain_size: FloatProperty(
            name="Size Constraint",
            description="Scale the model by 10 until it reaches the "
                        "size constraint (0 to disable)",
            min=0.0, max=1000.0,
            soft_min=0.0, soft_max=1000.0,
            default=10.0,
            )
    use_image_search: BoolProperty(
            name="Image Search",
            description="Search subdirectories for any associated images "
                        "(Warning, may be slow)",
            default=True,
            )
    use_apply_transform: BoolProperty(
            name="Apply Transform",
            description="Workaround for object transformations "
                        "importing incorrectly",
            default=True,
            )

    def execute(self, context):
        from . import import_3ds

        keywords = self.as_keywords(ignore=("axis_forward",
                                            "axis_up",
                                            "filter_glob",
                                            ))

        global_matrix = axis_conversion(from_forward=self.axis_forward,
                                        from_up=self.axis_up,
                                        ).to_4x4()
        keywords["global_matrix"] = global_matrix

        return import_3ds.load(self, context, **keywords)


@orientation_helper(axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
class Export3DS(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Export to 3DS file format (.3ds)"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.autodesk_3ds"
    bl_label = 'Export 3DS'

    filename_ext = ".3ds"
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
            default="*.3ds",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )

    use_selection: BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=False,
            )

    def execute(self, context):
        from . import export_3ds

        keywords = self.as_keywords(ignore=("axis_forward",
                                            "axis_up",
                                            "filter_glob",
                                            "check_existing",
                                            ))
        global_matrix = axis_conversion(to_forward=self.axis_forward,
                                        to_up=self.axis_up,
                                        ).to_4x4()
        keywords["global_matrix"] = global_matrix

        return export_3ds.save(self, context, **keywords)


# Add to a menu
def menu_func_export(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(Export3DS.bl_idname, text="3D Studio (.3ds)")


def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(Import3DS.bl_idname, text="3D Studio (.3ds)")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Import3DS)
#     TODO: Restore export
#     bpy.utils.register_class(Export3DS)

    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Import3DS)
#    TODO: Restore export
#     bpy.utils.unregister_class(Export3DS)

    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)

# NOTES:
# why add 1 extra vertex? and remove it when done? -
#  "Answer - eekadoodle - would need to re-order UV's without this since face
#  order isnt always what we give blender, BMesh will solve :D"
#
# disabled scaling to size, this requires exposing bb (easy) and understanding
# how it works (needs some time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Please help me!

Comment: Appears  you have folders named `appdata` and `AppData` in your user folder.

Comment: I don't. The 2 names lead to the same folder

Comment: Is it (_or it is_) possible one is a symbolic link (shortcut) to the other?  Could you please type  `bpy.utils.script_paths('addons')` into blender's python console and report back the result?  See python docs, an `__init__.py` file in a modules base folder "defines" the module, hence would not remove it.

Comment: It gives
['D:\\Programmes\\Blender\\2.90\\scripts\\addons', 'C:\\Users\\Scover\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.90\\scripts\\addons', 'C:\\Users\\Scover\\appdata\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.90\\scripts\\addons']

Comment: THere is the issue, blender is treating as two separate paths. Not a link?  I no longer use MS windoze since XP.  My limited understanding with latter versions of MS windows can set folder / file names as case sensitive or insensitive on a per folder basis. Have you perhaps added the lowercase version of the path (up to scripts) to `User Prefs > File Paths > Scripts`.  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/file_paths.html#file-paths

Answer (score 1):

I had the same path in *User Prefs > File Paths > Scripts*
Removing the path fixed the problem

Comment: As re my  last comment under question. In as much as it is the _"same path"_  on case insensitive  windows, compounding the issue is the difference in case.   _eg_ can you confirm that had your chosen the path  from filebrowse, or pasted in such that they match as a string, the same issue persists. Perhaps something for the devs to look at re testing for any two paths having equivalent target folder. ,